# error in building model "ner_ontonotes_bert_mult" in DeepPavlov

Tags: deeppavlov

I'm trying to build model "**ner_ontonotes_bert_mult**" via GoogleColab using example in [documentation](https://docs.deeppavlov.ai/en/0.5.1/features/models/ner.html#:%7E:text=The%20following%20Python%20code%20can%20be%20used%20to%20infer%20the%20model):

```
from deeppavlov import build_model, configs
ner_model = build_model(configs.ner.ner_ontonotes_bert_mult, download=True)
```

but get error:
**TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'num_tags'**

p.s. if I try to load another model (e.g. "ner_rus_bert"), the error does not appear

Full error (* maybe the error is related to directoty /packages/deeppavlov/models/torch_bert/crf.py* ):

```
2022-12-17 13:08:23.235 INFO in 'deeppavlov.download'['download'] at line 138: Skipped http://files.deeppavlov.ai/v1/ner/ner_ontonotes_bert_mult_torch_crf.tar.gz download because of matching hashes
INFO:deeppavlov.download:Skipped http://files.deeppavlov.ai/v1/ner/ner_ontonotes_bert_mult_torch_crf.tar.gz download because of matching hashes
Some weights of the model checkpoint at bert-base-multilingual-cased were not used when initializing BertForTokenClassification: ['cls.predictions.transform.LayerNorm.weight', 'cls.predictions.transform.LayerNorm.bias', 'cls.predictions.bias', 'cls.predictions.decoder.weight', 'cls.seq_relationship.bias', 'cls.predictions.transform.dense.weight', 'cls.predictions.transform.dense.bias', 'cls.seq_relationship.weight']
- This IS expected if you are initializing BertForTokenClassification from the checkpoint of a model trained on another task or with another architecture (e.g. initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForPreTraining model).
- This IS NOT expected if you are initializing BertForTokenClassification from the checkpoint of a model that you expect to be exactly identical (initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForSequenceClassification model).
Some weights of BertForTokenClassification were not initialized from the model checkpoint at bert-base-multilingual-cased and are newly initialized: ['classifier.bias', 'classifier.weight']
You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.
2022-12-17 13:08:30.1 ERROR in 'deeppavlov.core.common.params'['params'] at line 108: Exception in <class 'deeppavlov.models.torch_bert.torch_transformers_sequence_tagger.TorchTransformersSequenceTagger'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/deeppavlov/core/common/params.py", line 102, in from_params
    component = obj(**dict(config_params, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/deeppavlov/models/torch_bert/torch_transformers_sequence_tagger.py", line 182, in __init__
    super().__init__(optimizer=optimizer,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/deeppavlov/core/models/torch_model.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/deeppavlov/models/torch_bert/torch_transformers_sequence_tagger.py", line 295, in load
    self.crf = CRF(self.n_classes).to(self.device)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/deeppavlov/models/torch_bert/crf.py", line 13, in __init__
    super().__init__(num_tags=num_tags, batch_first=batch_first)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'num_tags'
ERROR:deeppavlov.core.common.params:Exception in <class 'deeppavlov.models.torch_bert.torch_transformers_sequence_tagger.TorchTransformersSequenceTagger'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/deeppavlov/core/common/params.py", line 102, in from_params
    component = obj(**dict(config_params, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/deeppavlov/models/torch_bert/torch_transformers_sequence_tagger.py", line 182, in __init__
    super().__init__(optimizer=optimizer,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/deeppavlov/core/models/torch_model.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/deeppavlov/models/torch_bert/torch_transformers_sequence_tagger.py", line 295, in load
    self.crf = CRF(self.n_classes).to(self.device)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/deeppavlov/models/torch_bert/crf.py", line 13, in __init__
    super().__init__(num_tags=num_tags, batch_first=batch_first)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'num_tags'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-5e156706e7e4> in <module>
      1 # from deeppavlov import configs, build_model
      2 
----> 3 ner_model = build_model(configs.ner.ner_ontonotes_bert_mult, download=True)

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/deeppavlov/core/commands/infer.py in build_model(config, mode, load_trained, install, download)
     53                             .format(component_config.get('class_name', component_config.get('ref', 'UNKNOWN'))))
     54 
---> 55         component = from_params(component_config, mode=mode)
     56 
     57         if 'id' in component_config:

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/deeppavlov/core/common/params.py in from_params(params, mode, **kwargs)
    100                 kwargs['mode'] = mode
    101 
--> 102             component = obj(**dict(config_params, **kwargs))
    103             try:
    104                 _refs[config_params['id']] = component

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/deeppavlov/models/torch_bert/torch_transformers_sequence_tagger.py in __init__(self, n_tags, pretrained_bert, bert_config_file, attention_probs_keep_prob, hidden_keep_prob, optimizer, optimizer_parameters, learning_rate_drop_patience, learning_rate_drop_div, load_before_drop, clip_norm, min_learning_rate, use_crf, **kwargs)
    180         self.use_crf = use_crf
    181 
--> 182         super().__init__(optimizer=optimizer,
    183                          optimizer_parameters=optimizer_parameters,
    184                          learning_rate_drop_patience=learning_rate_drop_patience,

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/deeppavlov/core/models/torch_model.py in __init__(self, device, optimizer, optimizer_parameters, lr_scheduler, lr_scheduler_parameters, learning_rate_drop_patience, learning_rate_drop_div, load_before_drop, min_learning_rate, *args, **kwargs)
     96         self.opt = deepcopy(kwargs)
     97 
---> 98         self.load()
     99         # we need to switch to eval mode here because by default it's in `train` mode.
    100         # But in case of `interact/build_model` usage, we need to have model in eval mode.

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/deeppavlov/models/torch_bert/torch_transformers_sequence_tagger.py in load(self, fname)
    293         self.model.to(self.device)
    294         if self.use_crf:
--> 295             self.crf = CRF(self.n_classes).to(self.device)
    296 
    297         self.optimizer = getattr(torch.optim, self.optimizer_name)(

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/deeppavlov/models/torch_bert/crf.py in __init__(self, num_tags, batch_first)
     11 
     12     def __init__(self, num_tags: int, batch_first: bool = False) -> None:
---> 13         super().__init__(num_tags=num_tags, batch_first=batch_first)
     14         nn.init.zeros_(self.transitions)
     15         nn.init.zeros_(self.start_transitions)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'num_tags'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using the latest version of DeepPavlov by running:

`!pip install deeppavlov`

Then import all the required packages:

`from deeppavlov import configs, build_model`

Install the model's requirements and download the pretrained model:

`ner_model = build_model(configs.ner.ner_ontonotes_bert_mult, download=True, install=True)`

You can get more information about this model and many others in our recent Medium [article](https://medium.com/deeppavlov/introducing-deeppavlov-library-1-0-0-an-open-source-natural-language-processing-library-7bfa02569ffe).